# Display Output In Browser Perl CGI SSH

Tags: perl, ssh, cgi, openssh

I'm executing remote commands using Net::OpenSSH using a web frontend. My commands return without failure on the command line, but I get nothing in a web browser. I've done a couple hour research to no avail--any ideas?

Here is some code to give you an example (some removed for obvious reasons).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use CGI ':standard';
use Net::OpenSSH;
# Here in the code is just the header and standard tags
print "1";
print "2"; # both display
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host, user => $uname, key_path => $key); # all works
$ssh- error and die "Can't ssh to host" . $ssh->error;
print "3";
$ssh->system("uname -a") or
die "remote command failed: " . $ssh->error;
my @lsa = $ssh->capture("ls -a");
$ssh->error and
die "remote ls command failed: ". $ssh->error;

print "4";
print "5"; 
print @lsa; # won't display in browser, just terminal/CLI
```

Cheers!

Comment: `$ssh- error and die` ? typo in the sample or worse? :)

Comment: Also, what does server error log say?

Comment: And what is the server and OS?

Answer (score 1):

I maintain CGI.pm. I recommend these additions to your simple script:

1. Before you print anything else, print the standard HTTP header: `print header()`;
2. Add this after the `use CGI` line: `use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);` ... that will display any run-time problems in the browser. If you don't get any output after these changes, check that the script compiles with `perl -cw script.pl`

Answer (score 0):

Below is about the minimum Perl code that worked for me on Debian machine.  I suggest you go through it and compare it to your actual code.

However, it did not work out-of-the box on my Debian, I had make some decisions most of which probably aren't very safe, but that's more about specific environment:

- make home for user that server runs writable (/var/www)
- add host to ~/.ssh/known_hosts beforehand
- use the `strict_mode => 0` to bypass `Net::OpenSSH`'s security checks instead of finding proper
   `ctl_dir` (`Net::OpenSSH` requires that the folder *and all above folders* are 0755 or more strict,
   so /tmp I used is normally not good enough)

I believe there are much safer practices than that, but as I said, that's specific to environment.

So the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::OpenSSH;
use File::Temp qw/ tempdir /;

# necessary minimum for CGI
print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";

# prepare temp dir
my $temp = tempdir("/tmp/sshme.pl-XXXXXXXX", CLEANUP => 1);

# open SSH session
my %opts = (
    user        => "user",
    password    => "password",
    ctl_dir     => $temp,
    strict_mode => 0            ## NOT recommended - see my comments
);
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new("host", %opts);
$ssh->error
    and die "Couldn't establish SSH connection: ". $ssh->error;

# perform command and print output
my @lines = $ssh->capture("ls")
    or die "remote command failed: " . $ssh->error;
print @lines;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your errors get directed to standard error, not standard output. In that case, they'll usually end up in the server log, not the browser window. Perhaps you can use `POSIX::dup2` to avoid this:

```perl
use POSIX;

# Make sure to send HTTP headers before redirecting streams!

POSIX::close(2);  # close original stderr stream. No more output to apache logs!!!
POSIX::dup2(1,2); # redirect error stream to standard output, so errors will appear in browser.
```

Processes launched by perl, like e.g. some ssh binary, will inherit these streams.